# Create video filter using GPUImage framework for blw file exported from Photoshop

Tags: ios, filter, rgb, cmyk, gpuimage

My task on project is to create `GPUImage` live video and image filter.

I have Black and white file exported from `Photoshop`.
I can read values from that file[image: black and white filter screenshot]

But can not find appropriate filter to implement it.

I have tried using two `GPUImageRGBFilters`, one for `RGB` values, and the other for `CMY` values. But the result is not what i need.

Has anyone the idea how to solve it using `GPUImage` framework.

Comment: Did you check OpenCV framework?

Comment: No, because on our project we are using GPUImage framework.

Comment: I´m interested in an fragment shader for using Photoshop settings, too. GPUImage is using OpenGL/fragment shaders for image manipulation.